# FileManager going to ANR

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am launching `FileManager` with Intent as below

```
    private void pickFile() {
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
       intent.setType("file/*").addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
       startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FILE_RESULT_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       switch (requestCode) {
          case PICK_FILE_RESULT_CODE: {
              Log.d("Mass", "inside onActivityResult PICK_FILE_RESULT_CODE path:" + Util.getRealPathFromUri(mContext, data.getData()));
              launchFileUploadActivity(Util.getRealPathFromUri(mContext, data.getData()));
           }
           break;
    }
}
    private void launchFileUploadActivity(String path) {
         Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), UploadActivity.class);
         i.putExtra("filePath", path);
         i.putExtra(Constants.KEY_APP_NO, mTrackData.getId() + "");
         i.putExtra("isImage", false);
         startActivity(i);
    }
```

If I don't select any file in `FileManager` and clicks back , its going to ANR not understanding what wrong hapening. Its not even coming to `onActivityResult`. Please some one suggest me. I want to launch a intent just like how `gmail` launches for attachment.

When I click attachment in gmail app I get this Logcat for ActivityManager

```
{act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=*/* flg=0x3080000 cmp=com.android.documentsui/.DocumentsActivity (has extras)} from uid 10068 on display 0
I/ActivityManager( 2420): Start proc 29052:com.android.documentsui/u0a40 for activity com.android.documentsui/.DocumentsActivity
I/ActivityManager( 2420): Start proc 29074:com.android.externalstorage/u0a10 for content provider com.android.externalstorage/.ExternalStorageProvider
I/ActivityManager( 2420): Displayed com.android.documentsui/.DocumentsActivity: +988ms (total +1s334ms)
```

is there any way to create such intent reffering this logcat

Comment: Post your `onActivityResult `

Comment: @omainegra please view my updates, I added onActivityResult code

Comment: Do you get ANR or NPE???

Comment: I am getting ANR @omainegra

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `launchFileUploadActivity` check that `data` and `data.getData()` are not `null`.

```
if (data != null && data.getData() != null)
    launchFileUploadActivity(Util.getRealPathFromUri(mContext, data.getData()));
```

Comment: still no use , same behavior  even after null checking

Comment: @SharanabasuAngadi Please check if it's the same error.

Comment: no , control is not even coming to onActivityResult